# How to list the file created using command $touch " " having blankspaces only in the name of the file

Tags: unix, grep

I want to list the file which only have blankspaces in the name nothing else.

e.g file created using command `touch "   "`.

This will create a file having 3 blank spaces.

I am using the following command but it's not listing the desired files.

```
ls -lart | grep '[^a-zA-Z0-9]'
```

Answer (score 3):

[Do not parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Instead, you can use `find` with regular expressions:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '^.*/ *$'
```

Since `man find` says *This is a match on the whole path, not a search*, we can just say (credits to John Kugelman):

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/ *'
```

This will find files consisting in multiple spaces.

Comment: @JohnKugelman true, I hadn't checked such case. Thanks, updated to use proper regexs

Comment: The anchors shouldn't be necessary. The man page says: "This is a match on the whole path, not a search."

Comment: Thank you for sharing valuable information. Now I won't use ls for parsing.  Could you please share some good article related to find command use.

Comment: @mukulshukla there are some good examples in the [Find documentation topic](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/566/find#t=201608250745001794096). Also, since it has many, many options, you may prefer looking for some info on specific cases (find by size, type, creation date...)

Answer (score 1):

You can list it the same way you would any file: by name, or with a pattern that matches only it.

```
ls -lart "   "
```

The pattern requires `shopt -s extglob` in `bash` (other shells may have something simliar). One possibility:

```
ls -lart "+([[:space:]])"
```